# How to set global variables for UserForms in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, global, userform

I made a module in Excel VBA that takes a large sum of data, asks the user which columns to plot, then plots it. I wanted to try and turn it GUI based so that the user doesn't have to memorize the names of all of the column headers (there's over 150 headers), but I need a global String array to hold each column header that the user wants to plot.

I'm not sure how to even declare a global variable in a UserForm properly. I've looked up how, and I can't find anything specific to a UserForm. I saw that you need to have the keyword Global, but it's giving me a compile error as soon as I put a variable with a Global keyword in.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test_output")
    Dim index As Long
    Dim len As Integer
    Dim colChar As String
    
    index = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1

    ' Making sure a value is selected to plot
    If Not index = -1 Then
        ' Converting to column char
        colChar = Split(Cells(1, CInt(index)).Address, "$")(1)
        ' Add to global string array
        len = UBound(colNames) - LBound(colNames)
        colNames(len) = colChar
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test_output")
    Dim i As Long
    Global colNames() As String ' ERROR with this line
    
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    ' Populating the ComboBox
    For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("1:1"))
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I think everything else as of right now is working fine, I just don't know what to do about making a Global variable to hold an array of String column sections.

Comment: In a module, declare `Public myvar As ....` and you can call it from any object in your file (worksheets, modules, userforms, classes). [Public statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/public-statement)

Comment: worth adding, i think, that this is before any sub or function in the module or in a clean module